# Error webpacking library source maps in ES6 app, works in ES5 app

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, webpack, babeljs

I distribute an ES6 library, transpiled to ES5, with source maps using this `webpack.config.js`

```
var webpack = require("webpack");

module.exports = {
  entry: ['./src/MyLib.js'],
  output: {
    path: __dirname,
    filename: 'dist/bundle.js',
    libraryTarget: 'umd',
    library: "MyLib"
  },
  module: {
    loaders: [
      {
        test: /\.js$/,
        loader: 'babel',
        query: { presets: ['es2015'] }
      },
      {
        test: /\.css$/,
        loader: "style-loader!css-loader"
      }
    ]
  },
  devtool: 'source-map'
};
```

As hinted in [Webpack's `devtool` docs](http://webpack.github.io/docs/configuration.html#devtool)
I use the [`source-map-loader`](https://github.com/webpack/source-map-loader) to make the library source maps available in an ES5 app that uses the library. It works with this webpack.config.js

```
var path = require("path");

module.exports = {
  entry: './main.js',
  output: {
    filename: 'dist/bundle.js'
  },
  module: {
    preLoaders: [
      {
        test: /\.js$/,
        loader: 'source-map',
        include: /my-lib/
      }
    ]
  },
  resolveLoader: {
    root: path.join(__dirname, "node_modules"),
  },
  devtool: 'source-map'
};
```

The problem is that when the consumer of the library is an ES6 app, with the following `webpack.config.js`, which just adds the babel loader to the config file that works for the ES5 app,

```
var path = require("path");

module.exports = {
  entry: './main.js',
  output: {
    filename: 'dist/bundle.js'
  },
  module: {
    preLoaders: [
      {
        test: /\.js$/,
        loader: 'source-map',
        include: /my-lib/
      }
    ],
    loaders: [
      {
        test: /\.js$/,
        loader: 'babel',
        query: { presets: ['es2015'] }
      }
    ]
  },
  resolveLoader: {
    root: path.join(__dirname, "node_modules"),
  },
  devtool: 'source-map'
};
```

then, when running webpack, there's an error like

```
ERROR in ./~/my-lib/dist/bundle.js
Module build failed: Error: /Users/xavi/Development/my-lib/examples/es6/node_modules/my-lib/dist/bundle.js: Invalid mapping: {"generated":{"line":8,"column":0,"lastColumn":null},"source":null,"original":{"line":null,"column":null},"name":null}
...
```

Why this source maps configuration works when the consumer is an ES5 app but not when it's an ES6 app transpiled with Babel? How to make the library source maps available in the ES6 app?

Comment: Your Babel setup will make babel run on all your library code too, generally I'd avoid that since it'll be way slower and it makes Babel have to process and permute the original library sourcemaps.

Comment: That makes sense and it worked. Thanks! (I would accept your reply as the answer if I could.)

Comment: Wasn't sure it would be enough!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Babel must have some issues ingesting your library's sourcemaps, and since you have `test: /\.js$/,`, Babel will process every single JS file in your repo, including `node_modules`.

I'd recommend restricting that `test` to only match files you want Babel to process, and that will likely be enough to avoid this, though it doesn't resolve the underlying issue.